# Where is the GNU Pascal Compiler?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, pascal

On Ubuntu 10.04 I had installed the GNU Pascal Compiler (package gpc).

After moving to Ubuntu 12.04 / 64 bit I cannot find the package any more. Google and the GNU Pascal [homepage](http://www.gnu-pascal.de) did not help much.

So I wanted to ask if the package has been discontinued, renamed, or moved to a different repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that gpc was [removed from Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=613588) (and subsequently Ubuntu) in February 2011 due to the project being unmaintained/discontinued.

Comment: +1 This explains a lot. I think I will have to move to the Free Pascal Compiler (package `fp-compiler`).

Comment: @Giorgio Or you can attempt to download and build `gpc` from source. (Or try to install an old .deb package...)

Comment: @Eliah Kagan: True, I will give it a try.

Comment: The GNU Developers 2010 parting message named GCC major version migrations and general cumbersome C development as a reason (Later gcc started to also allow C++)

Answer (score 3):

PPA versions of the GNU Pascal Compiler for Ubuntu can be downloaded from https://launchpad.net/~ueter/+archive/ubuntu/gpc-3.4

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly gpc, but if you don't mind an alternative, you could use Free Pascal. This will install the IDE and compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install fp-ide
```

Note that the IDE is terminal based. To start it from the prompt:

```
fp
```

For reference, see http://fusharblog.com/installing-free-pascal-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Or have a look at the Lazarus package, which is a more GUI IDE for Free Pascal

Answer (score 3):

You can install the Free Pascal compiler alone using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install fp-compiler
```

...then invoke and run a simple program such as:

```pascal
program Hello;
begin
  writeln ('Hello, world.');
end.
```

...using the following commands:

```
fpc hello.pas
./hello
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try getting an rpm and converting it using alien, as per this post on the gpc mailing list:
http://www.g-n-u.de/pipermail/gpc/2013-June/015249.html

quote:

You might be able to use one of these.
https://software.opensuse.org/package/gpc

I converted the Fedora package with 'Alien' and its working for me on
Debian (64 bit).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.